# inner measure is not finitely additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need to show that there exist disjoint subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $$m_*(A \cup B) > m_*(A) + m_*(B).$$

I see the analogous proof for outer measure case, but the proof use contradiction which relies heavily of Caratheodory measurability theorem for outer measure. I have never seen Caratheodory Theorem for inner measure case.

So I wonder :
1. if there is analogous result for Caratheodory for inner measure ?
2. If not, is there a direct constructive proof like construction of the vitali nonmeasurable set that can use to prove this ?